# How to determine programmatically in c# that a type accepts null value or not?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

I know merely checking for whether the type is not a value type is not sufficient. How can i account for those Nullable?

**DUPLICATE**

[How to check if an object is nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable)

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Nullable.GetUnderlyingType that will return null if the type is not nullable.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the keyword [default(YourType)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(VS.80).aspx) ?

> Whether T will be a reference type or a value type.
>
> If T is a value type, whether it will be a numeric value or a struct.

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
 bool nullable = yourType.IsGenericType && yourType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>))
```