# .NET: How do I tell if a type is nullable?

Tags: .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if an object is nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable)

I have a System.Type object which may be a `Nullable<T>`. How would I determine this at runtime?

Note: At this point I don't care what T is, I just need to know whether or not it is a Nullable.

Comment: Do you mean it's actually a `Nullable<T>` generic object, or that it's a class and can be a null value?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Possible duplicate:

[How to check if an object is nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable)

if not..

```
bool IsNullableType(Type theType)
{
    return (theType.IsGenericType && 
    theType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)));
}
```

Comment: That is overkill; there is a much easier approach in the "possible duplicate" link

Comment: yeah, that's why that is pasted on the top.. :)