# How to determine if a non-null object is a Nullable struct?

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-4.0, nullable, value-type

Is there anyway to know this?

I found one post that asked a very similar question at  [How to check if an object is nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable)  The answer explains how to determine if an object is nullable **if there is access to a Generic Type Parameter**.  This is accomplished by using `Nullabe.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T))`.  However, if you only have an object and it is not null, can you determine if it is actually a Nullable ValueType?

In other words, is there a better way than checking every possible nullable value type individually to determine if a boxed struct is a value type?

```
void Main(){
    Console.WriteLine(Code.IsNullableStruct(Code.BoxedNullable));
} 


public static class Code{
    private static readonly int? _nullableInteger = 43;

    public static bool IsNullableStruct(object obj){
                  if(obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
                  if(!obj.GetType().IsValueType) return false;
                  return IsNullablePrimitive(obj);
            }
    public static bool IsNullablePrimitive(object obj){
         return obj is byte? || obj is sbyte? || obj is short? || obj is ushort? || obj is int? || obj is uint? || obj is long? || obj is ulong? || obj is float? || obj is double? || obj is char? || obj is decimal? || obj is bool? || obj is DateTime? || obj is TimeSpan?;
    }

    public static object BoxedNullable{
        get{ return _nullableInteger; }
    }
}
```

-

### Update

I found [this article at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), and it says you can't determine if a type is a Nullable struct via a call to `GetType()`.

-

### Update #2

Apparently the method I suggested doesn't work either because `int x = 4; Console.WriteLine(x is int?);` is True.  (See the comment)

Comment: That actually doesn't work. `obj is int? == true` if obj is `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting Jon Skeet's comment in the question you linked:

> there's no such thing as a boxed nullable type - Nullable gets boxed to a null reference or a boxed int

so in your example program by the time `BoxedNullable` is passed to `IsNullableStruct` which takes an `object` as a parameter, the value is already a boxed `43`, no longer a nullable anything.  Ironically `x is int?` is `true` for any `int`, nullable or otherwise, so that only adds to the confusion.

In any case, your original question, according to Jon's comment, doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: [Here is the article on MSDN which explains this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

When you box a nullable, it actually boxes its underlying type.  Nullable<int> will turn into a boxed int.  There is no way to tell if the source of an boxed value type was a Nullable.

Note that your `IsNullablePrimitive` will actually return true if you pass it a non-Nullable int!

Answer (score 0):

Nullable<> is a special class.  When you try to inspect or copy a Nullable<> it is converted/boxed to either 'null' or the value type it contains.  Calling GetType() would actually throw an exception if your Nullable<> doesn't have a value, or at best return the underlying type.  The spoofing occurs at the lowest level.  You cannot identify a Nullable<> through any kosher means.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you simply check the generic definition:

```
protected bool IsNullableType(Type type)
{
    if(!type.IsGeneric)
        return false;

    return type.GetGenericDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);
}
```

Effectively, these statements are the same:

```
var type = typeof(Nullable<>);
var type2 = new Nullable<int>().GetType().GetGenericDefinition();
```

Comment: (1) Your syntax is wrong.  (2) Assuming you intended the equivalent to `return !type.IsGenericType ? false : type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);`, your answer is still incorrect.  The two statements are not equivalent, try it out

Comment: Those statements are _not_ the same.  Nullable<T>.GetType() actually returns T.

Comment: Interesting. I learn something new every day! I would have expected it to work like almost every other generic out there.