# Detecting a Nullable Type via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable

Surprisingly the following code fails the Assert:

```
int? wtf = 0;
Assert.IsType<Nullable<int>>(wtf);
```

So just out curiosity, how can you determine if a given instance is a Nullable<> object or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if an object is nullable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable)

Comment: If you're also looking for NRT (C# 8) reflection, have a look at Namotion.Reflection, https://github.com/RicoSuter/Namotion.Reflection

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Well firstly, `Nullable<T>` is a struct, so there isn't an *object* as such. You can't call `GetType()`, as that will box the value (at which point you either get null and thus an exception, or a boxed non-nullable value and therefore not the type you want).

(Boxing is what's messing up your assertion here - I would assume that `IsType` accepts `object`.)

You can use type inference though to get the type of the *variable* as a type parameter:

```
public bool IsNullable<T>(T value)
{
    return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null;
}
```

That's not a huge amount of use when you know the exact type at compile-time as in your example, but it's useful for generics. (There are alternative ways of implementing it, of course.)

What's your real life situation? I assume it's not an assertion like this, given that you know the answer to this one at compile time.

Comment: Very tricky! That appears to do it. Now I just have to remember why I wanted to know that...

Comment: Also I never realized that structs don't have a GetType() but I should have figured that out since I understand that they get boxed for such things.

Comment: @justin.m.chase: Structs inherit `GetType` from `object` - but because the call is non-virtual, they can't *override* it, which means the value is always boxed... which then screws things up when the original value is nullable.

Comment: To see if it is any nullable type you can do this:

(type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals( typeof(Nullable<>) ));

Comment: @Andre: Yes, but I find using `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` simpler :)

Answer (score 11):

I like the @jon-skeet answer but it only works if you know the type you are testing against. In our world we are using reflection to open up objects and test values against regex expressions.

simplifying the extension to work for any type worked better for us.

```
public static bool IsNullable(this Type type)
{
    return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null;
}
```

generics are life's blood but sometimes... :)

Comment: This would cause a boxing operation when you tried to get the Type of a struct though right? Compared to Jon's.

Answer (score 5):

```
int? i = 0;
var type = TypedReference.GetTargetType(__makeref(i));
var isNullable = type.IsGenericType &&
    type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);
```

Comment: This is brilliant, it gives the declared type (not underlying type as in `object i = 0; i.GetType() == typeof(int);`). But if it is to get declared type why not make us of type inference simply? Like, `public Type GetDeclaredType<T>(this T t) { return typeof(T); }`. Much more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Only this way worked in my case using .net core 7

```
MyClass mclass = new MyClass();    

PropertyInfo[] properties = mclass.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties)
{
   bool nullable = propertyInfo.GetMethod is null ? false : new NullabilityInfoContext().Create(propertyInfo.GetMethod.ReturnParameter).ReadState == NullabilityState.Nullable;
   if (nullable)
      {
        //some script to do
      }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to expand this to show how you're getting the `propertyInfo`.

Comment: @justin.m.chase Thanks for your comment, Answer is updated now after expanding the code to clearify how did i get the propertyInfo var.

Comment: This is useful for PropertyInfo cases, which can mask the nullability behind the Get method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What namespace is `Assert` in?

The following returns `true` as you would expect:

```
int? wtf = 0;
if (typeof(Nullable<int>).IsInstanceOfType(wtf))
{
    // Do things
}
```

Although its worth noting that `typeof(Nullable<int>).IsInstanceOfType(42)` also returns true - this is because this method accepts an `object` and so gets boxed as a `Nullable<int>`.

Comment: Assert in my case was in Xunit but I was just trying to say in general that that statement should succeed.

Comment: Also, I don't think the above works... well technically it returns true but I believe it's a false positive because this also returns true: typeof(Nullable<int>).IsInstanceOfType(0)

Comment: @Kragen: Try it with `int wtf = 0;` and `int? wtf = null;` for some surprising results. Boxing makes it impossible for such a method signature to really do what you want. EDIT: After your edit, there's still a problem - `42` does *not* get boxed as a `Nullable<int>`. Rather, `0` gets boxed as an `int` boxed type. There is no way of constructing a boxed value of a nullable type.

Comment: @Jon How come `typeof(Nullable<int>)` return true for an `int` boxed type in that case?

Comment: @Kragen: It looks like `Type.IsInstanceOfType` is basically treating nullable types and non-nullable types as equivalent. Try `typeof(int).IsInstanceOfType(wtf)` with your initial code, for example. I can't immediately find this documented, which is rather worrying...

Comment: @Jon I've figured it out by looking at the implementation using Reflection - its because `typeof(int?).IsAssignableFrom()` is true. (Seems like a bit of an odd choice, especially after having read the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype.aspx))

Comment: @Kragen: `0 is int?` same thing puzzled me too, first time I saw it.

Comment: @Rick Looking at the documentation `0 is int?` makes sense (you can cast an `int` to an `int?`), but `0` isn't **actually** an instance of `int?`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with, as everything else seemed to fail - at least on *Portable Class Library* / *DotNet Core* with >= C# 6

Basically you extend generic Type `Object` and `Nullable<T>` and use the fact that the static extension method that matches the underlying type is going to be invoked and takes precedence over the generic `T` extension-method.

```
public static partial class ObjectExtension
{
    public static bool IsNullable<T>(this T self)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and one for `Nullable<T>`

```
public static partial class NullableExtension
{
    public static bool IsNullable<T>(this Nullable<T> self) where T : struct
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Using Reflection and `type.IsGeneric` and `type.GetGenericParameters()` did not work on my current set of .NET Runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

It works fo me, hope for you too.

```
public static bool IsNullable(this Type type)
{
    return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Vladimir [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21780367/7678085):

```
public static class GenericExtensions
{
   public static bool IsNullable<T>(this T item) =>
     TypedReference.GetTargetType(__makeref(item)).FullName.Contains("System.Nullable");
}
```

Usage:

```
int? nullableInt = 42;
bool nIntIsNullable = nullableInt.IsNullable();
```

Duration: <2ms on average machine.

**Remarks:**

- [Important, this API is not CLS-compliant.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typedreference?view=net-6.0)
- `Contains("System.Nullable")` can be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to check wether a type is Nullable or not..

```
type.Assembly.FullName.StartsWith("System") && type.Name.Contains("Nullable");
```

Comment: Gross but checks out.

Comment: @justin.m.chase it is not that great but to check whether a prop is UserDefined  we may need to check  type.Assembly.FullName.StartsWith("System") && prop.Type.IsClass. So it ain't that bad