# How know the nullable type by reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting a Nullable Type via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026824/detecting-a-nullable-type-via-reflection)

I have  this code :

```
string type = string.Empty;
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties();
foreach (var item in propertyInfos)
    if (item.Name.ToUpper() == searchField.ToUpper())
    {
        type = item.PropertyType.FullName;
        break;
    }   

switch (type)
{
    case "System.Int32":
        //...
        break;
    case "System.Single":
        //...
        break;
}
```

The code works but the problem is when the type is a nullable. How know if the type is a nullable ? The nullable type (int32? long? double?) and how convert a string into this nullable type ?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you do any research before posting the question here?? Doesn't look like that as @Habib had found. Please do some reachable before posting any question :)

Answer (score 0):

try out below code will help you for that

```
System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fieldsInfos = typeof(NullWeAre).GetFields();

        foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi in fieldsInfos)
        {
            if (fi.FieldType.IsGenericType
                && fi.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
            {
                // We are dealing with a generic type that is nullable
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Type: {1}", fi.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(fi.FieldType));
            }

    }
```