# How to Determine Nullability (NRT) of Generic Type Parameter?

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection, c#-10.0, nullability

For example, I might have a method with the following signature:

```
public async Task<ViewModel?> GetPersonUri()
```

Using reflection I would like to determine if the type parameter of `Task` is a nullable reference type. In the case, the answer would be yes. If it were:

```
public async Task<ViewModel> GetPersonUri()
```

the answer should be no.

How can I determine the nullability of a generic type parameter?

Comment: See [this document](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/nullable-metadata.md) for details on how nullable metadata is stored

Comment: I think that information is available with reflection. On the Type with `typeof(T)` or `GetType()` on the object you can get all Properties or just one. On the `PropertyInfo` object I think you can find a boolean `IsNullable` (not 100% shure).

Comment: It's a bit different. Take a look here somewhere further down the page you'll find a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026824/detecting-a-nullable-type-via-reflection

Comment: @PaulSinnema I believe the SO answer you're referring to has nothing to do with C# 8.0 NRTs.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes it does! Thx!!!

Comment: Note that you can close your own question as a dupe (without having to wait for others to vote).

Answer (score 2):

**In .NET 6 onwards**, we gained the `NullabilityInfoContext` type, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71549957/1086121) for details.

Prior to this, you have to manually inspect the attributes yourself.  This seems to do the trick:

```
public static bool GenericReturnTypeIsNullable(MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
    var nullableAttribute = methodInfo!.ReturnTypeCustomAttributes.GetCustomAttributes(true)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType().FullName == "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute");
    if (nullableAttribute != null)
    {
        var flagsField = nullableAttribute.GetType().GetField("NullableFlags");
        var flags = (byte[]?)flagsField?.GetValue(nullableAttribute);
        return flags != null && flags.Length >= 2 && flags[1] == 2;
    }
    
    if (CheckNullableContext(methodInfo.CustomAttributes))
        return true;
    
    for (var type = methodInfo.DeclaringType; type != null; type = type.DeclaringType)
    {
        if (CheckNullableContext(type.CustomAttributes))
            return true;
    }
    
    static bool CheckNullableContext(IEnumerable<CustomAttributeData> customAttributes)
    {
        var context = customAttributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeType.FullName == "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContextAttribute");
        return context != null &&
            context.ConstructorArguments.Count == 1 &&
            context.ConstructorArguments[0].ArgumentType == typeof(byte) &&
            (byte)context.ConstructorArguments[0].Value! == 2;
    }

    return false;
}
```

[See it on dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BOavIK).

See [this spec doc](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/nullable-metadata.md) for details.

We end up needing to check a number of things.

If the method has a `Nullable` attribute on its return value, its `NullableFlags` field is a byte array, where each member of the array refers to successive generic types. A `0` means null-oblivious, `1` means not nullable, `2` means nullable. So in:

```
[return: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Nullable(new byte[] { 1, 2 })]
public Task<string?> Foo() => ...
```

The `1` refers to the `Task<T>` itself, and indicates that it's not nullable. The `2` refers to the first generic type parameter, i.e. the `string?`, and indicates that it is nullable.

If this attribute doesn't exist, we need to check for a `NullableContext` attribute on the method itself. This provides a default nullability for everything which doesn't have a specified `Nullable` attribute. This takes a single byte, again `0` to `2`.

If the method doesn't have this attribute, it might be on the containing type, or its containing type. Keep looking upwards until we find one (or not).

The slightly tricky bit is that the compiler emits the `Nullable` and `NullableContext` attributes directly into the assembly, which means that each assembly will have its own definition. So we need to use reflection to access them - we can't cast anything to a `NullableAttribute` or `NullableContextAttribute`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. However, we can leverage the new .NET 6 reflection API as outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71545936/c-sharp-detect-nullable-reference-type-from-generic-argument-of-methods-return. Basically, I must admit that my question seems to be a duplicate of that one as Jeroen pointed out.

Comment: Yep, see the first sentence of my answer