# Nullability of generic type arguments

Tags: c#, .net, nullability

So far I've worked with `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` and even `NullabilityInfo.WriteState` to determine the nullability of types. This worked well - sometimes.

I'd like to know the nullability of the `Dictionary<string, string?>` generic type arguments:

```cs
Type baseType = typeof(Dictionary<string, string?>)!;
Type[] gp = baseType.GetGenericArguments();
Assert.IsNull(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(gp[0]));// Ok
Assert.IsNotNull(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(gp[1]));// Fail
```

I can't use a `NullabilityInfoContext` here, because I do only have the type, but not a reflection info object available.

Now my idea was to look for the compiler attribute `NullableAttribute`:

```cs
string nat = "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute";
Assert.IsTrue(gp[1].GetCustomAttributes(inherit: false).Any(a => a.GetType().ToString() == nat));// Ok
```

This does not really work, because:

```cs
Assert.IsTrue(gp[0].GetCustomAttributes(inherit: false).Any(a => a.GetType().ToString() == nat));// Ok
```

I can't access any information of the `NullableAttribute`, so it doesn't help here.

I wonder why `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` returns `null` for the second generic argument `string?`? I expected the method to return `typeof(string)` instead.

Even when I do `typeof(Dictionary<string, string?>).ToString()` or or `gp[1].ToString()`, I don't get any nullability information in the output.

My understanding now is, that

- `NullabilityInfo` helps to determine a reflection info objects nullability
- `NullableAttribute` contains information that I can't access from code - it won't help anything
- `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` doesn't always work as expected, seems useless in this context

and this leaves me with questions:

1. Where would I need `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`, where would it work as I expect, and where else is won't?
2. How can I determine the nullability of a generic type argument?
3. Is nullability more an IDE feature than it does affect anything real in the CLR?

I'd really like to have a way to find out, if the author of the code that I'm inspecting with reflections did use `string` or `string?` as generic parameter, because I want to switch my own code on that condition.

**Update**: I tried the reflection code I found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71585611/10797322 , too, but the `NullableAttribute` flags are always `0`, and the `NullableContextAttribute` constructor parameter is always `1` - for BOTH generic type arguments.

Comment: You cannot. `typeof(Dictionary<string, string>)` and `typeof(Dictionary<string, string?>)` produce the same IL. Nullable reference types are kind of like Java's generics in some sense. The runtime doesn't know about them. Metadata like `NullableAttribute` are sometimes added, but not always.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you! "The runtime doesn't know about them" - ok, that's what I assumed, too. This would mean, that it's more an IDE feature. and I guess it helps the compiler to match the correct overloaded target method or constructor. Anyway, I still need to know the nullability of generic arguments - there's no way around for me.

Comment: Nullable initialization checks for reference types are a language feature, not a runtime feature, so you won't be able to figure this out through reflection. Check this reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types#nullable-references-and-static-analysis