# Detecting nullable types in C#

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a method that is defined like such:

```
public bool IsValid(string propertyName, object propertyValue)
{
  bool isValid = true;
  // Validate property based on type here
  return isValid;
}
```

I would like to do something like:

```
if (propertyValue is bool?)
{
  // Ensure that the property is true
}
```

My challenge is, I'm not sure how to detect whether my propertyValue is a nullable bool or not. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: how is `IsValid` called?

Comment: Is PropertyValue always going to be either of type bool or type bool?

If so, you should overload the method to be explicit to the two valid types coming in.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/374663/937411

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The value of `propertyValue` could *never* be a `Nullable<bool>`. As the type of `propertyValue` is `object`, any value types will be boxed... and if you box a nullable value type value, it becomes either a null reference, or the boxed value of the underlying non-nullable type.

In other words, you'd need to find the type without relying on the *value*... if you can give us more context for what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to help you more.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use generics for this but I think you can check the nullable underlying type of propertyvalue and if it's bool, it's a nullable bool.

```
Type fieldType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(propertyvalue));
if (object.ReferenceEquals(fieldType, typeof(bool))) {
    return true;
}
```

Otherwise try using a generic

```
public bool IsValid<T>(T propertyvalue)
{
    Type fieldType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(fieldType, typeof(bool))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a long shot, but could you use generics and a method overload to let the compiler work this out for you?

```
public bool IsValid<T>(string propertyName, T propertyValue)
{
    // ...
}

public bool IsValid<T>(string propertyName, T? propertyValue) where T : struct
{
    // ...
}
```

Another thought: is your code attempting to go through every property value on an object? If so, you can use reflection to iterate through the properties, and get their types that way.

### Edit

Using `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` as [Denis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704738/denis-pitcher) suggested in his answer would get around the need to use an overload.