# Are these tests for Nullable Type equivalent?

Tags: c#, nullable

Here is the condition I used to detect if we are dealing with a Nullable Type :

```
System.Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(itemType) != null
```

and here the code of my teammate :

```
itemType.IsGenericType && itemType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)
```

We actually didnt find a case where one will return `true` and the other `false` (or vice-versa) but are these 2 snippets strictly equivalent ?

Comment: As I understand it, the non-nullable types are a small finite list.  Would it not be more efficient to identify by their presence?

Comment: @Jeremy: Any `struct` you create is a non-nullable type. I can't imagine trying to create a list of them.

Comment: Maybe my question isnt clear but the test has to return true with "int ? a" and false with "int b"

Comment: As per my understanding of code, your teammate is first checking whether the itemType is Generic type or not and then whether that Generic Type is Nullable or not..

Comment: @Gabe also, Jeremy is using another interpretation for 'Nullable Type' than the OP. Jeremy appears to understand it as 'reference type'

Comment: @Vijay: You typed two exclamation marks. Why is that?

Comment: @Vijay yes, cause itemType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() crash if the type is not generic, that's why there is this first test

Comment: @GuillaumeSlashy so that checks are alright, do u want to know other methods to check wheher a given type is Nullable or not than what ur teammate has written?

Comment: I just wanna know if they both are "absolutely" correct ! (I mean, they'll handle every Nullable possible Type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN for Nullable.GetUnderlyingType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx):

> The type argument of the nullableType parameter, if the nullableType parameter is a closed generic nullable type; otherwise, null.

So, yes it is safe to use the former version.

Decompiled from GetUnderlyingType:

```
public static Type GetUnderlyingType(Type nullableType)
{
  if (nullableType == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("nullableType");
  Type type = (Type) null;
  if (nullableType.IsGenericType && !nullableType.IsGenericTypeDefinition && nullableType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (Nullable<>))
    type = nullableType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
  return type;
}
```

Comment: Yep, but is it different from the 2nd one ?

Comment: See edited answer: it is the same albeit marginally safer and slightly less efficient (unless the compiler inlines it)

Answer (score 1):

These 2 snippets are not fully equivalen.
Here is the test case that returns a different values for each snippets:

```
Type t = typeof(Nullable<>);

bool c1 = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) != null; //false
bool c2 = t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>); //true
```

Thus the Nullable.GetUnderlyingType method more safe, because it's implementation already include this test case checking:

```
public static Type GetUnderlyingType(Type nullableType) {
    if (nullableType == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("nullableType");
    Type type = null;
    if ((nullableType.IsGenericType && !nullableType.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
        && (nullableType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))) {
        type = nullableType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }
    return type;
}
```

Comment: Yep, just get it from sehe's answer ! Thx anyway

Answer (score 1):

*Your teammate's code is perfectly fine* as given in the `MSDN` documentation (excerpt):
***Use the following code to determine whether a Type object represents a Nullable type. Remember that this code always returns false if the Type object was returned from a call to GetType.***

```
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)) {…}
```

explained at the below MSDN link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789.aspx

Moreover, there is a similar discussion at this SO QA:

[How to check if an object is nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever testing whether a type is nullable, I've always used the second method you posted:

```
itemType.IsGenericType && itemType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)
```

I haven't had a problem with this!

Regards,

Comment: We feel like they both are good, but at the same time, we feel like in a certain context, one of them won't work...

Answer (score 0):

dotPeek shows this:

```
public static Type GetUnderlyingType(Type nullableType)
{
  if (nullableType == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("nullableType");
  Type type = (Type) null;
  if (nullableType.IsGenericType && !nullableType.IsGenericTypeDefinition && object.ReferenceEquals((object) nullableType.GetGenericTypeDefinition(), (object) typeof (Nullable<>)))
    type = nullableType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
  return type;
}
```

The only difference I see is if `itemType` is itself generic, ie. `typeof (List<>)`, his will fail.  And your is slightly slower because it has to actually find the underlying type.