# Type checking on Nullable<int>

Tags: c#

If have the following method:

```
static void DoSomethingWithTwoNullables(Nullable<int> a, Nullable<int> b)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Param a is Nullable<int>: " + (a is Nullable<int>));
    Console.WriteLine("Param a is int          : " + (a is int));
    Console.WriteLine("Param b is Nullable<int>: " + (b is Nullable<int>));
    Console.WriteLine("Param b is int          : " + (b is int));
}
```

When i call this method with null as a parameter, the type check returns false for this parameter. For example this code

```
DoSomethingWithTwoNullables(5, new Nullable<int>());
```

results in this output:

```
Param a is Nullable<int>: True
Param a is int          : True
Param b is Nullable<int>: False
Param b is int          : False
```

Is there any way to preserve the type information when using a Nullable and passing null? I know that checking the type in this example is useless, but it illustrates the problem. In my project, I pass the parameters to another method that takes a `params object[]` array and tries to identify the type of the objects. This method needs to do different things for `Nullable<int>` and `Nullable<long>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going straight to the underlying problem, no, you can't do this. A null `Nullable<int>` has exactly the same boxed representation as a null `Nullable<long>`, or indeed a 'normal' null. There is no way to tell what 'type' of null it is, since its underlying representation is simply all-zeros. See [Boxing Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms228597%28v=vs.85%29) for more details.

Comment: Because b is first boxed to `int?` resulting in a null reference.

Comment: Presumably you could do try { } catch { } to test it, so there IS a way of finding out. I bet using reflection you could take that a step further and polish it. Maybe initialise a new instance, which should give it a default value, and do `typeof(variable.value)` ?

Comment: @SLC: You can't. It is just a null reference without type information.

Comment: @SLC I've never seen a better explanation than this, from Microsoft's VP of the dev division (I don't remember what his title was when he wrote this): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2005/08/11/450640.aspx

Comment: Actually, there is no underlying representation, any more than there's an underlying representation of `(string)null` or `(object)null`.

Comment: You are right, Nullables without value are boxed to null: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms228597(v=vs.85). So I need to pass additional type info or use another approach to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

conceptually, `new Nullable<int>` **is** `null`.

If we generalise, forgetting about `Nullable<T>`:

```
string s = null;
bool b = s is string;
```

we get `false`. `false` is the *expected* value for a type-check on a `null` value.

Comment: What if he did `b = 3;`? If it's a string then you'd get an error, but if it was an int or nullable int you wouldn't get an error?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Reflection to achieve this. [Relevant article here.](http://weblogs.asp.net/grantbarrington/archive/2009/03/17/using-reflection-to-determine-whether-an-type-is-nullable-and-get-the-underlying-type.aspx)

Comment: You can't use reflection. Calling `GetType()` on a null reference will throw `NullReferenceException`. There is no type associated with the null reference. The article linked is based on types and not references to objects (which in this case may be null).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `null` does not point to any specific memory location, and thus there is no metadata that you can associate with it to lookup the type. Thus, you cannot gain any additional information about the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, you can get the type using `GetType()`. For example,

```
int? myNullableInt = null;
Console.WriteLine(myNullableInt.GetValueOrDefault().GetType());
```

If `myNullableInt` is null, a default value will be returned. Check the type of this returned value and, in this case, it will return `System.Int32`. You can do an `If..else`/`Switch` check on the returned type to perform the relevant action.

(`int?` is the same as `Nullable<int>`)

Comment: Or you could just call `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType()`

Comment: Or that. Either way, it does seem possible to get the information required in this question.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know whether the given object is a Nullable. It could also be a string or a plain int. I thought I could use the typecheck to get this information. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @bernd_rausch Maybe this answer may help here http://stackoverflow.com/a/374663/187697 If it returns true, carry on with the code in my post, otherwise assume that it's not nullable and do a normal type check.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, nor should you want to.  Since `Nullable<T>` is a struct, value-type variables of this type *have all the type information you need at compile time.*  Just use the `typeof` operator.

On the other hand, you might have a Nullable instance whose type you don't know at compile time.  That would have to be a variable whose static type is `object` or some other reference type.  Howver, because a `Nullable<T>` value boxes to a boxed `T` value, there's *no such thing as a boxed `Nullable<T>`.*  That instance whose type your checking will just be a `T`.

This is why you get the same result for `is int` and `is Nullable<int>`.  There's no way to distinguish between a boxed `int` and a boxed `int?`, because there is no boxed `int?`.

See [Nulls not missing anymore](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2005/08/11/450640.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been pointed out `null` has no type. To figure out if something is `int?` vs `long?` you need to use reflection to get information about something storing the type. Here is some code that you may be able to use as inspiration (not knowing exactly what you try to achieve the code is a bit weird):

```
class Pair<T> where T : struct {

  public Pair(T? a, T? b) {
    A = a;
    B = b;
  }

  public T? A { get; private set; }

  public T? B { get; private set; }

}

void DoSomething<T>(Pair<T> pair) where T : struct {
  DoMore(pair);
}

void DoMore(params object[] args) {
  Console.WriteLine("Do more");
  var nullableIntPairs = args.Where(IsNullableIntPair);
  foreach (Pair<int> pair in nullableIntPairs) {
    Console.WriteLine(pair.A);
    Console.WriteLine(pair.B);
  }
}

bool IsNullableIntPair(object arg) {
  var type = arg.GetType();
  return type.IsGenericType
    && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Pair<>)
    && type.GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(int);
}
```

If you execute the following code

```
DoSomething(new Pair<int>(5, new int?()));
DoSomething(new Pair<long>(new long?(), 6L));
```

you get the following output:

```
Do more
5
null
Do more
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use typeof :

```
a == typeof(Nullable<int>) //true
a == typeof(int) //false
```