# How to determine if a runtime object is of a nullable value type

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable

First: this is not a duplicate of [How to check if an object is nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable). Or, at least, there was no useful answer provided to that question, and the author's further elaboration actually asked how to determine whether a given **type** (eg. as returned from MethodInfo.ReturnType) is nullable.

However, that is easy. The hard thing is to determine whether a runtime object whose type is unknown at compile time is of a nullable type. Consider:

```
public void Foo(object obj)
{
    var bar = IsNullable(obj);
}

private bool IsNullable(object obj)
{
    var type = obj.GetType();
    return type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);
    // Alternatively something like:
    // return !(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null);
}
```

This does **not** work as intended, because the `GetType()` call results in a boxing operation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789.aspx), and will return the underlying value type, rather than the nullable type. Thus `IsNullable()` will always return false.

Now, the following trick uses type parameter inference to get at the (unboxed) type:

```
private bool IsNullable<T>(T obj)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    return type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);
}
```

This seems initially promising. However, type parameter inference only works when the type of the object is known at compile time. So:

```
public void Foo(object obj)
{
    int? genericObj = 23;

    var bar1 = IsNullable(genericObj);   // Works
    var bar2 = IsNullable(obj);          // Doesn't work (type parameter is Object)
}
```

In conclusion: the general problem is not to determine whether a type is nullable, but to get at the type in the first place.

So, my challenge is: how to determine if a runtime object (the obj parameter in the above example) is nullable? Blow me away :)

Comment: By the time you've got the value as `object`, you've got a boxed value anyway. You need to remove that boxing operation. Unfortunately, we don't know what the context is here, which makes it hard to give an answer... if you *only* have a variable of type `object`, you've lost the relevant information already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're too late. A boxed value no longer has the type information you seek - boxing a `int?` value results either in `null`, or a boxed `int`. In a way, it's an analogue to calling `GetType` on `null` - it doesn't really make sense, there's no type information.

If you can, stick with generic methods instead of boxing as much as possible (`dynamic` can be very helpful for some of the interfaces between actual nullable values and `object`s). If you can't, you'll have to use your own "boxing" - or even just creating your own `Nullable`-like type, that will be a `class` rather than a very hacky `struct`-like thing :D

If needed, in fact, you can even make your `Nullable` type a `struct`. It's not the `struct`-ness that breaks the type information - it's not the boxing itself that destroys that information, it's the CLR hacks that enable `Nullable` to match the performance of non-nullable values. It's very smart and very useful, but it breaks some reflection-based hacks (like the one you're trying to do).

This works as expected:

```
struct MyNullable<T>
{
  private bool hasValue;
  private T value;

  public static MyNullable<T> FromValue(T value) 
  { 
    return new MyNullable<T>() { hasValue = true, value = value }; 
  }

  public static implicit operator T (MyNullable<T> n) 
  {
    return n.value;
  }
}

private bool IsMyNullable(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) return true; // Duh

    var type = obj.GetType().Dump();
    return type.IsGenericType 
           && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyNullable<>);
}
```

Doing the same with `System.Nullable` doesn't; even just doing `new int?(42).GetType()` gives you `System.Int32` instead of `System.Nullable<System.Int32>`.

`System.Nullable` not a real type - it gets special treatment by the runtime. It does stuff that you simply can't replicate with your own types, because the hack isn't even in the type definition in IL - it's right in the CLR itself. Another nice abstraction leak is that a nullable type is not considered a `struct` - if your generic type constraint is `struct`, you can't use a nullable type. Why? Well, adding this constraint means it's legal to use e.g. `new T?()` - which wouldn't be possible otherwise, since you can't make a nullable of a nullable. It's easy with the `MyNullable` type I've written here, but not with the `System.Nullable`.

**EDIT**:

The relevant part of the CLI specification (1.8.2.4 - Boxing and unboxing a value):

> All value types have an operation called box. Boxing a value of any
>   value type produces its boxed value; i.e., a value of the
>   corresponding boxed type containing a bitwise copy of the original
>   value. If the value type is a nullable type—defined as an
>   instantiation of the value type System.Nullable—the result is a
>   null reference or bitwise copy of its Value property of type T,
>   depending on its HasValue property (false and true, respectively). All
>   boxed types have an operation called unbox, which results in a managed
>   pointer to the bit representation of the value.

So by definition, the `box` operation on nullable types produces either a null reference or the stored value, never a "boxed nullable".