# Simplest way to check is a certain Type is Nullable (including string)

Tags: c#

what is the best way to check if a certain Type is nullable or not.

some suggested codes out there are unable to test other Type especially string.

Comment: Yes that's fine, but its a duplicate. Already asked and answered.  Make sure to check for duplicates before you ask a new question.

Comment: In fact this was was created AFTER he already posted the answer in that

Comment: Well, that's what happens when you try to game the system for a few measly rep points.  Its quickly spotted and you lose far more than you gain.

Comment: sorry, i didn't know i would lose some point from it. noted, hehe

Comment: `string` is a reference type, so it's nullable by definition

Comment: yeah but If you are creating a generic you will never know if the generic type is a string or not. Example, if you are trying to create an Extension for IEnumerable to generate a DataTable from it with the help of Reflection

Answer (score 1):

```
!certainType.IsValueType || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(certainType) != null
```

Comment: this code doesn't work is you try to check typeof(string)

Answer (score -3):

the simplest way to do it:

```
    public static bool IsNullable(this Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsValueType) return Activator.CreateInstance(type) == null;
        return true;
    }
```

these are my unit tests and all passed

```
    IsNullable_String_ShouldReturn_True
    IsNullable_Boolean_ShouldReturn_False
    IsNullable_Enum_ShouldReturn_Fasle
    IsNullable_Nullable_ShouldReturn_True
    IsNullable_Class_ShouldReturn_True
    IsNullable_Decimal_ShouldReturn_False
    IsNullable_Byte_ShouldReturn_False
    IsNullable_KeyValuePair_ShouldReturn_False
```

actual unit tests

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void IsNullable_String_ShouldReturn_True()
    {
        var typ = typeof(string);
        var result = typ.IsNullable();
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IsNullable_Boolean_ShouldReturn_False()
    {
        var typ = typeof(bool);
        var result = typ.IsNullable();
        Assert.IsFalse(result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IsNullable_Enum_ShouldReturn_Fasle()
    {
        var typ = typeof(System.GenericUriParserOptions);
        var result = typ.IsNullable();
        Assert.IsFalse(result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IsNullable_Nullable_ShouldReturn_True()
    {
        var typ = typeof(Nullable<bool>);
        var result = typ.IsNullable();
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IsNullable_Class_ShouldReturn_True()
    {
        var typ = typeof(TestPerson);
        var result = typ.IsNullable();
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IsNullable_Decimal_ShouldReturn_False()
    {
        var typ = typeof(decimal);
        var result = typ.IsNullable();
        Assert.IsFalse(result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IsNullable_Byte_ShouldReturn_False()
    {
        var typ = typeof(byte);
        var result = typ.IsNullable();
        Assert.IsFalse(result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IsNullable_KeyValuePair_ShouldReturn_False()
    {
        var typ = typeof(KeyValuePair<string, string>);
        var result = typ.IsNullable();
        Assert.IsFalse(result);
    }
```

Comment: you answered your own question?

Comment: Answering your own question is allowed normally.  But in this case he's taken his answer to another question http://stackoverflow.com/a/32063068/325727 and created a new duplicate question just to post the exact same answer again.  So downvotes are fully deserved here.

Comment: well that is also my answers -VJPPaz, i didn't know is a bad idea to repost the answer. i should learn from it XD