# C# How to check if an object is nullable

Tags: c#

I saw a question and answer in stack overflow

[How to check if an object is nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable)

I could not put a comment in the above because I do not have more than 50 comments and that is why I am asking a question in here.

```
if(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(myType) !=null)
{
   // It's Nullable
}
```

If myType is system.string

```
Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(myType)
```

returns null

I thought System.string is null-able !

Comment: Did you try to read the answer and all the code, as opposed to copying the line that looks relevant? The `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType()` only works for value types.

Comment: An object is always nullable, because it's a reference value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType()` doesn't return anything meaningful for `typeof(string)`. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype(v=vs.110).aspx) mentions:

> Returns the underlying type argument of the specified **nullable type**.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> The type argument of the nullableType parameter, **if the nullableType parameter is a closed generic nullable type**; otherwise, null.

In other words, it only returns something useful if you actually pass it a type that implements `Nullable<T>`, for example `int?`, `bool?`, and so on. *That* is what's being meant by a "nullable type" here.

You can also see its intended usage in the code from [Marc's answer to the question you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/374663/):

```
static bool IsNullable<T>(T obj)
{
    // ...
    if (!type.IsValueType) return true; // ref-type
    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null) return true; // Nullable<T>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Nullable<T>` - is a special structure, so `System.string` is not `Nullable<T>`, `System.string` is a class. All classes can be null.
So,

```
if (myType.IsClass)
{
    //can be null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All reference types can be set to null, but are not of the `Nullable<T>` type, you can check if a type is a reference type by using `!myType.IsValueType`

Answer (score 1):

System.String (or string) is a reference type. This means, instances of this type can be `null`. Nullables are a way to add this functionality to value types (like the primitive types `bool`, `int` etc.).

Answer (score 1):

`Nullable` is a type, not a property of a type. `System.String` is nullable, but it is not a `Nullable`, unlike `int?`, which is a shortcut for `Nullable<System.Int32>`. All reference types in C# are nullable (you can pass a null reference), while the `Nullable` type can only accept a non-nullable value type as an argument.

If you want to check if a given type can accept `null` as a value, you can do something like this:

```
bool CanBeNull<T>()
{
  return default(T) == null;
}
```

Of course, this already makes the assumption that the default value is the null value, which isn't necessarily the case; but it will work for both reference types and `Nullable` value types. If you have to deal with a value type that accepts null but not as the default value, you'll have to add it specifically. There isn't really a sure and simple way to check if a given type can be assigned null other than actually trying to assign a null value.

Indeed, what "can be assigned null" means is something that depends very much on the compiler. For example, doing something like `int? someValue = null;` actually calls the constructor of `int?` - it's equivalent to `int? someValue = new int?();`.

If you don't know the type at compile-time (so you can't use generics), you can add a check for whether the given type is a value type:

```
if (!type.IsValueType) // Can be assigned null
```

Make sure you treat classes, value types and interfaces correctly. And of course, just being able to assign a `null` value to a local/field doesn't mean it's necessarily a valid value. In the end, the decision is yours.