# Differentiate if an object is of type DateTime or Nullable<DateTime> (DateTime?)

Tags: c#, datetime, compare, nullable

How can I differentiate if an object is of type DateTime or NullableDateTime> (DateTime?)?

I understand why the following code does not work, but can you help me with a solution that does?

```
    public void Test()
    {
        DateTime? dateTime1 = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
        DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
        DoSomething(dateTime1);
        DoSomething(dateTime2);
    }

    public void DoSomething(object value)
    {
        if (value is DateTime?)
        {
            //Do something
        }
        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            //Do something else
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (value?.GetType() == typeof(DateTime?)) { … }`

Comment: This also does return false for both test cases (dateTime1 and dateTime2)

Comment: Not sure why this question got closed, the linked answer is clearly not what OP wants.

Comment: This returns true only for dateTime1. If you want to have true for dateTime2 just replace DateTime? with DateTime.

Comment: @ckuri I did, 'if (value?.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))' does return true for dateTime1 and dateTime2, 'if (value?.GetType() == typeof(DateTime?))' does return false in both cases

Comment: @TheWho what is concrete use-case? Why do you need to know that it is nullable `DateTime`?

Comment: [How to identify a nullable value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#how-to-identify-a-nullable-value-type) You should avoid using `is` operator here

Comment: An exact duplicate [How to check if an object is nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible due to how nullabale value types are [boxed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#boxing-and-unboxing) in C#:

> - If HasValue returns false, the null reference is produced.
> - If HasValue returns true, the corresponding value of the underlying value type T is boxed, not the instance of Nullable.

So basically there is no such thing as boxed nullable value types.

Not sure what your actual case it, but in provided scenario you can make your method generic and use `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T value)
{
    var typeOfT = typeof(T);
    if(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeOfT) == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("nullable dt");
    }
    else if(typeOfT ==  typeof(DateTime))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("dt");
    }
}

DoSomething(dateTime1); // prints "nullable dt"
DoSomething(dateTime2); // prints "dt"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
      public void Test()
      (
        DateTime? dateTime1 = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1); 
        DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
        DateTime? dateTime3 = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dateTime4 = DateTime.Now.Date;

        **//here you can pass any datetime variable from above**
        DoSomething(dateTime1 == null ? null : dateTime1);
        DoSomething(dateTime2);
       }

   
   public void DoSomething(DateTime? value)
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out DateTime Temp) == true  && value != null)
        {
            //do stuff if dateTime variable not null & correct formate
            var d = value;
        }
        else
        {
            //do stuff if dateTime variable null
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to call `ToString` on `value` which is `Datetime?`?