# How to use declaration pattern of "is" operator with ternary operator?

Tags: c#

```
int? a = null;
var b = (a is (int?) y) ? "bla bla bla" : y.ToString();
```

> The name `y` does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Even if this would be allowed syntactically, it would be wrong to access `y` in the "else" part of the ternary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not supported.

If you look at the MS documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#how-to-identify-a-nullable-value-type

Then down a little it states

> Also, don't use the is operator to determine whether an instance is of
> a nullable value type. As the following example shows, you cannot
> distinguish types of a nullable value type instance and its underlying
> type instance with the is operator:

it says you should

> Instead use the Nullable.GetUnderlyingType from the first example and
> typeof operator to check if an instance is of a nullable value type.

See also the answer here, which provides a nice method `IsNullable`

[How to check if an object is nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable)